# Why does the answer key say "the world is changing" instead of "the world changes"?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

The world *(change)*. Nothing never stays the same.

The key answer: the world **(is changing)**.

Why can't we say: the world **changes?** Isn't it *a fact*? I mean it should be in **present simple** (world changes).

Comment: Of course we _can_ say _"The world changes"_. We need to see the _entire question exactly as it is written_. If the question really says _"Nothing never stays the same"_, we will know that the exam was written either by a non-English speaker or by a speaker of the AAVE dialect (which is unlikely).

Comment: *changes* would be fine, too. Get rid of this book. This is a bad answer, and an ungrammatical question: *Nothing never stays the same* should be *Nothing **ever** stays the same*.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Negative harmony is not restricted to AAVE: it is very common in my own dialect, and still was when Alabama was openly segregated.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, that's true, as several lyrics just verified. We don't know, though, whether the negative harmony originated in the book/exam or in transcription. If the latter, we can at least eliminate a crappy text.